# Adding caption to Facebook 4.x using FBSDKShareLinkContent

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

In facebook SDK 3.x it was possible to use the share dialog to add a caption. Is this feature available in 4.x? Should the caption now be part of the web page the share is pointing to?

As of right now, the caption being shown is just the weblink.

Here's some code to clarify question:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];
content.contentDescription = @"2-4 sentences of description.";
content.contentTitle = @"Title";
content.contentCaption = ?

shareDialog.shareContent = content;
shareDialog.delegate = self;
[shareDialog show];
```

Note - obviously there is no 'contentCaption' setter but maybe it's a property? Not sure if it's even available anymore but figured I would ask.

Comment: I don't think it's available anymore, but you can: 1. Let the user type the text on the Share Dialog, or 2. If you own the shared site, you can set the Open Graph tags

Answer (score 0):

I am using Facebook sdk v4.10.1 now and this is work for me.

```
[content setValue:@{@"caption":@"?"} forKey:@"feedParameters"];
```